# Converting date format to YYYY-MM-DD from YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS format in Logstash for nginx error logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am having nginx error logs  of the below form:-

> 2015/09/30 22:19:38 [error] 32317#0: *23 [lua] responses.lua:61:
>   handler(): Cassandra error: Error during UNIQUE check: Cassandra
>   error: connection refused, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST
>   /consumers/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8001"

As mentioned [here](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1663?focusedCommentId=20224&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-20224) I am able to parse this logs.

My filter configuration is like the below:-

```
filter {  
  grok {
      match => {
        "message" => [
          "%{DATESTAMP:mydate} \[%{DATA:severity}\] (%{NUMBER:pid:int}#%{NUMBER}: \*%{NUMBER}|\*%{NUMBER}) %{GREEDYDATA:mymessage}",
          "%{DATESTAMP:mydate} \[%{DATA:severity}\] %{GREEDYDATA:mymessage}",
          "%{DATESTAMP:mydate} %{GREEDYDATA:mymessage}"
        ]
      }
      add_tag => ["nginx_error_pattern"]
    }

    if ("nginx_error_pattern" in [tags]) {      
      grok {
        match => {
          "mymessage" => [
            "server: %{DATA:[request_server]},"
          ]
        }        
      }

      grok {
        match => {
          "mymessage" => [
            "host: \"%{IPORHOST:[request_host]}:%{NUMBER:[port]}\""
          ]
        }        
      }

      grok {
        match => {
          "mymessage" => [
            "request: \"%{WORD:[request_method]} %{DATA:[request_uri]} HTTP/%{NUMBER:[request_version]:float}\""
          ]
        }        
      }

      grok {
        match => {
          "mymessage" => [
            "client: %{IPORHOST:[clientip]}",
            "client %{IP:[clientip]} "
          ]
        }        
      }

      grok {
        match => {
          "mymessage" => [
            "referrer: \"%{DATA:[request_referrer]}\""
          ]
        }       
      }                
    }
}
```

`mydate` is having date of the form:-

```
"mydate" => "15/09/30 22:19:38"
```

Can someone let me know how can I add one more field (let's say `log_day`) having date of the form `2015-09-30`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is always a good idea to save the time/date in a field of type `date`. It enables you to do [complex range queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) with Elasticsearch or Kibana.

You can use [logstash's date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) to parse the date.

**Filter:**

```
date {
    match => [ "mydate", "YY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

**Result:**

```
"@timestamp" => "2015-09-30T20:19:38.000Z"
```

The date filter puts the result in the `@timestamp` field by default.

To **avoid the default mapping** into `@timestamp` field, specify the target field like "log_day", such as following:

**Filter:**

```
date {
    match => [ "mydate", "YY/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    target => "log_day"
}
```

**Result:**

```
"log_day" => "2015-09-30T20:19:38.000Z"
```

Once you have a field of type `date` you can proceed with further operations. You might use the [date_formatter](https://github.com/wiibaa/logstash-filter-date_formatter) filter to create another date field in your special format.

```
date_formatter {
        source => "log_day"
        pattern => "YYYY-MM-dd"
}
```

Result: `"log_day" => "2015-09-30"`

Comment: Thanks @hurb. This is working as expected. I have a follow up question. Can we do this without modifying the `@timestamp` field? Right now this will overwrite `@timestamp` with the date in log.

Comment: Sure, just add `target => "log_day"` to your date filter. See me edit.